# C# listview item images backround layout property

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, layout, imagelist

I have winform project that contains ListView and ImageList controls.

I want to listview item images backround layout property to "center".

I tried to change imagelist size property but every image has different size therefore, it does not meet what I want.

As you know PictureBox control has this property.

```
pictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
```

Similarly, can we apply this property to listview item images?

```
listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;

ImageList iList = new ImageList();
iList.ImageSize = new Size(64, 64);  
iList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
listView1.LargeImageList = iList;

// something like that
// iList.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
```

[image]

Comment: Set `OwnerDraw = true` and draw the images yourself in `DrawSubItem`

Comment: Thanx @Jimi. I searched but i could not find anything significant. Could you share a link with an example about this topic.